# Is it possible to take over the victim's system only by DNS attacks?

Tags: attack-prevention, dns

I found this article and it describes some DNS attacks.
Those are mainly targeting login credentials, banking information, and so forth.

By redirecting the victim to a malicious site it could be also possible to take over the whole system, as far as I understand.

Still, if my browser is secure (no js enabled, no pictures, all plugins deactivated) I should be safe, right?

Are there also attacks that could make it possible to take over a victim's system any other way then redirecting to a malicious website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A successful DNS redirection means the attacker can redirect you wherever he wants.

He can setup a malicious website to exploit your system by various techniques. One example would be the recent exploits from Hacking Team; two 0-Days that can be used to exploit a fully patched machine remotely without any user interaction on all systems running Flash.

So no, you wouldn't have been secure even with what you've mentioned with someone redirected you to a website like that.

Seeing how 0-Days are discovered frequently in all programs, you could face the same situation anytime, anywhere.

**Solution:** DNSCrypt.

**UPDATE:** with all plugins deactivated, you would've been secure actually. It's good you're decreasing the attack surface, but still, that was one example. You get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

if you look at the meaning of DNS you can find your answer :

> domain name server, the system that automatically translates Internet addresses to the numeric machine addresses that computers use.

With some DNS attacks you can redirect and pass victim's data to your server (e.g a mikrotik server), so you can sniff victim's data and **inject** something in the respond requests.

The best way is redirecting the victim to our server and forcing the user to download a **RAT** as a Windows update, or some such thing.

I think you can inject some malicious code to a request response and get access to a victim's system through exploiting the victim browser.

I should say you cannot find the browser's exploits or POC's easily in public web.